# Duplicating CAD line style in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, style, cad

I'm trying to convert some CAD maps and I was requested to make this line type look exactly the same. Normally I would make a line with arrows like that just using the line decoration or character markers but getting the groups of 3 that stay with the direction of the line is giving me a lot of trouble.

Anyone know a method to do this?

[image: Here is what they want.]

Comment: Can you create a special single marker consisting of three arrows, and then create your line as symbol-dash-symbol-dash-etc?

Comment: I had considered that. I was hoping there would be an easier solution as making those markers is quite difficult, but I believe you are right and that is the route I will need to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is scale dependent solution. I will assume that at 1:2000 scale the length of 3 arrows is 25 m. I suggest to split your lines twice: a) split all the lines into same length bits and b) split every odd into 3 parts and use arrow symbol for them. For this we need 1st produce shorter version of originals. So populate new integer field (N):

```
max(divmod(!Shape!.length,25)[0],1)
```

Populate new double field (TZ) by:

```
min( !Shape!.length, !N! *25)
```

Create copy of original and shorten each shape by running this on field Shape:

```
!Shape!.segmentAlongLine (0,!TZ!)
```

[image]

Split shortened lines into N bits:

[image]

and every odd one into 3:

[image]

Decide what to do with portion of line beyond 25*N and end of the line.